# Shuffle() returns same results

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, random

I'm having a problem with using a basic `shuffle()` function in Laravel. It returns the same result, which seems to be changing once every 10 or 20 minutes.

Here's the basic code I'm testing:

```
$ar = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
shuffle($ar);
var_dump($ar);
Log::info(json_encode($ar));
```

And here's the log:

[image]

Comment: is there a question here

Comment: @lagbox yes, why does shuffle is repeating the same set 8 times in a row

Comment: The code you shared is working as expected http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d311c9fd3b50cc8f2d40c78ff1cc46d97417e8e1

Comment: It does work outside of a Laravel Controller, but it behaves as you see inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably initialize your random seed with a constant value somewhere else.